# Using filter in graphql request in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, graphql

I need to make requests to an API using Google App Script. It took me a really long time to make it work, but a simple request is working. Here is the code that works:

```
function make_query() {
  
  url = "https://open-api.eprocorpo.com.br/graphql";
  
  var token = "mytoken"

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',Authorization: 'Bearer '+token},
        payload: JSON.stringify({
            query: `{
                      fetchLeads {
                          data {
                              createdAt
                              id
                              source {
                                  title
                              }
                              status {
                                  label
                              }
                              store {
                                  name
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }`,
        }),muteHttpExceptions:true
    });

  Logger.log(JSON.parse((response.getContentText())));

  }
```

It runs without a problem. My question is how I work in filter for date and pagination in this code. I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
function make_query_with_filters() {
  
  url = "https://open-api.eprocorpo.com.br/graphql";

  var token = "mytoken"

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',Authorization: 'Bearer '+token},
        payload: JSON.stringify({
          query: `query ($filters: LeadFiltersInput, $pagination: PaginationInput) {
              fetchLeads(filters: $filters, pagination: $pagination) {
                  data {
                createdAt
                id
                source {
                  title
                }
                status {
                  label
                  }
                store {
                  name
                }
              }
            }`,
            variables:{
              filters: {
                    createdAtRange: {
                        start: "2023-06-01",
                        end: "2023-06-01"
                    }
                },
              pagination: {
                  currentPage: 1,
                  perPage: 1
              }
          }   
        }),muteHttpExceptions:true
      });

  var resposta = JSON.parse((response.getContentText()));

  Logger.log(resposta);

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Filtering, pagination, sorting are not standard features of GraphQL - you need to look at the API docs for the GraphQL server you are using to see if and how they implement those functions.